# Specify IncrediBuild to use only local machine

Tags: c++, build, incredibuild

is there a way to specify IncrediBuild BuildConsole to use only local machine in the build, and don't use remote agents?

Comment: Some more infos would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.
Open Agent Settings -> Initiator -> General. Mark the "Enable standalone" option.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question,

the reason to use only local machine in the build was to properly track build time. And since it was automated, the standalone build should be specified from the console.

The IncrediBuild doesn't have such command argument, but standalone build could be achieved by passing to the command line argument

`/MaxWinVer=`

the version of the OS lower then all machines in the network, for example

`/MaxWinVer="VISTA"`

while there are only Windows8 machines in the network.